# Have I found a bug in PHP or have I missed something?

Tags: php, constructor, php4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my constructor still called even if the class and constructor case are different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659680/why-is-my-constructor-still-called-even-if-the-class-and-constructor-case-are-di)

```
<?php
 abstract class foo {
  function foof() {
   echo "Hello, I'm foo :)";
  }
 }

 class foo2 extends foo {
  function foo2f() {
   $this->foof();
  }
 }

 class foo3 extends foo2 {
  function foo3f() {
   $this->foo2f();
  }
 }

 $x = new foo3;
 $x->foo3f();
?>
```

This code outputs "Hello, I'm foo :)" (as expected) but when I change code to something like this: http://pastebin.com/wNeyikpq

```
<?php
abstract class foo {
 function fooing() {
  echo "Hello, I'm foo :)";
 }
}

class foo2 extends foo {
 function foo2() {
  $this->fooing();
 }
}

class foo3 extends foo2 {
 function foo3() {
  $this->foo2();
 }
}

$x = new foo3;
$x->foo3();
?>
```

PHP prints:

> Hello, I'm foo :)Hello, I'm foo :)

Why? Is it a bug?

Comment: I put second code on pastebin due to stackoverflow bug (lol) - http://cl.ly/3J352B14073S15282O2s

Comment: This is not a bug in PHP, and that's not a bug in StackOverflow.

Comment: In general, you're going to draw the ire of people here if your question assumes (even if you just mention it in passing) that there's a bug in the language you're using, and not in the code you've written.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are calling the foo2 two times, `function foo2()` in `foo2` it's a constructor.

Comment: +1 This is correct. See [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: _Note for passersby_: A method of the same name as its class is treated as a constructor for backward compatibility with PHP4. Starting in PHP5, you should use the [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method instead.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is not that `function foo2()` in `foo2` it's a constructor, although it's true that it's a constructor.

The answer is that `foo3()` is the constructor called in `new foo3()`. This constructor calls the method `foo2()`.

Actually the constructor of `foo2` newer is called since `foo3` has not a call to his parent constructor.

---

Because you are calling `foo3()` two times, `function foo3()` in `foo3` is a [constructor <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php):

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

First call:

```
$x = new foo3;
```

Second call:

```
$x->foo3f();
```

Give `foo3` a real constructor and you're fine:

```
class foo3 extends foo2 {
 function __construct() {};
 function foo3() {
  $this->foo2();
 }
}
```

Comment: +1, you actually coined it correctly first.